# Spark and YARN. How does the SparkPi example use the first argument as the master url?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm just starting out learning Spark, and I'm trying to replicate the `SparkPi` example by copying the code into a new project and building a jar. The source for `SparkPi` is: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkPi.scala

I have a working YARN cluster (running CDH 5.0.1), and I've uploaded the spark assembly jar and set it's hdfs location in `SPARK_JAR`.

If I run this command, the example works:

```
$ SPARK_CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/spark/examples/lib/spark-examples_2.10-0.9.0-cdh5.0.1.jar /usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi yarn-client 10
```

However, if I copy the source into a new project and build a jar and run the same command (with a different jar and classname), I get the following error:

```
$ SPARK_CLASSPATH=Spark.jar /usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-class spark.SparkPi yarn-client 10
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:113)
    at spark.SparkPi$.main(SparkPi.scala:9)
    at spark.SparkPi.main(SparkPi.scala)
```

Somehow, the first argument isn't being passed as the master in the SparkContext in my version, but it works fine in the example.

Looking at the SparkPi code, it seems to only expect a single numeric argument.

So is there something about the Spark examples jar file which intercepts the first argument and somehow sets the `spark.master` property to be that?

Comment: I haven't used YARN. In MESOS you need to set SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI to the HDFS uri of the spark.tar.gz and SPARK_HOME=boo (whatever), just to set the SPARK_HOME

Comment: I had a read around, and it seems that `SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI` is MESOS-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recent change — you are running old code in the first case and running new code in the second.

Here is the change: https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/44dd57fb66bb676d753ad8d9757f9f4c03364113

I think this would be the right command now:

```
/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit Spark.jar --class spark.SparkPi yarn-client 10
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Hadn't occurred to me that the SparkPi example on my distribution (0.9.0 I think) might have changed.